# Evaluate summation from k=0 to n of k(n-k)

Tags: combinatorics

How do I evaluate the summation from k=0 to n of k(n-k)?

I tried using block walking but can't seem to get anywhere. Any suggestions on approaches would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Split the sum up in to two sums:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}k(n-k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}[kn-k^2]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}kn-\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2.
$$